# Angular CLI - Cannot read property 'prefix' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-cli

i am trying to generate a component in my library folder using angular cli.

**Structure**

```
library/
projects/
angular.json
```

Within `library/` i run the following command.

```
ng g c mycomponent --skip-import
```

However i get the following error.

> Cannot read property 'prefix' of undefined

I have a multi project structure with a library folder that is used by each project. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-multiple-projects

**angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "socialscout": {
      "root": "projects/socialscout/",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/socialscout/src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/socialscout",
            "index": "projects/socialscout/src/index.html",
            "main": "projects/socialscout/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "projects/socialscout/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/socialscout/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "projects/socialscout/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/socialscout/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/socialscout/src/styles.scss",
              "projects/socialscout/src/custom.scss",
              "projects/socialscout/src/theme.scss"

            ],
            "scripts": [
                "node_modules/progressbar.js/dist/progressbar.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "projects/socialscout/src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "projects/socialscout/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "socialscout:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "socialscout:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "socialscout:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "projects/socialscout/src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "projects/socialscout/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/socialscout/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "projects/socialscout/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "projects/socialscout/src/styles.scss",
              "projects/socialscout/src/theme.scss"

            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "projects/socialscout/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/socialscout/src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "projects/socialscout/tsconfig.app.json",
              "projects/socialscout/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "socialscout-e2e": {
      "root": "projects/socialscout-e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "projects/socialscout-e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "socialscout:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "socialscout:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "projects/socialscout-e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
  "defaultProject": "untouchable-app",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am under the impression that angular cli works from the root of your project and applies changes to a directory named "src" have you made any changes to the angular configuration? Showing any changes may help us

Comment: Try this: `ng g c /library/mycomponent --skip-import`

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera with that command i get cannot read property sourceRoot of undefined.

Comment: I will update my question with angular.json